# Combine multiple extractor objects to use in one match statement

Tags: scala

Is it possible to run multiple extractors in one match statement?

```
object CoolStuff {
  def unapply(thing: Thing): Option[SomeInfo] = ...
}
object NeatStuff {
  def unapply(thing: Thing): Option[OtherInfo] = ...
}

// is there some syntax similar to this?
thing match {
  case t @ CoolStuff(someInfo) @ NeatStuff(otherInfo) => process(someInfo, otherInfo)
  case _ => // neither Cool nor Neat
}
```

The intent here being that there are two extractors, and I don't have to do something like this:

```
object CoolNeatStuff {
  def unapply(thing: Thing): Option[(SomeInfo, OtherInfo)] = thing match {
    case CoolStuff(someInfo) => thing match {
      case NeatStuff(otherInfo) => Some(someInfo -> otherInfo)
      case _ => None // Cool, but not Neat
    case _ => None// neither Cool nor Neat
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can try

```
object ~ {
  def unapply[T](that: T): Option[(T,T)] = Some(that -> that)
}

def too(t: Thing) = t match {
  case CoolStuff(a) ~ NeatStuff(b) => ???
}
```

Comment: @userunknown I've added a similar, less elegant, but more verbose answer, maybe you find it useful.

Comment: How it works: Consider a tree like `Branch(left, right)`. You can match on children, like this: `case Branch(Leaf(x), Leaf(y))`. Importantly, the whole match succeeds only if all the children successfully match. Those child matches are also capable of extracting values. This would be exactly what we want if it had the same value on either side of Branch. To achieve that, this same idea is used, except `left` and `right` refer to the same object, which is what was `match`ed on. On top of that, the name `~` is used (instead of `Branch`) in infix notation, which makes it look like "real syntax".

Comment: Or in other words, `~` matches anything and turns it into two of itself. That is, `999` matches as `~(999, 999)` (or sugared: `999 ~ 999`). This gives us two of the matched value to play with when using other match criteria.

Answer (score 5):

I've come up with a very similar solution, but I was a bit too slow, so I didn't post it as an answer. However, since @userunknown asks to explain how it works, I'll dump my similar code here anyway, and add a few comments. Maybe someone finds it a valuable addition to cchantep's minimalistic solution (it looks... *calligraphic?* for some reason, in a good sense).

So, here is my similar, aesthetically less pleasing proposal:

```
object && {
  def unapply[A](a: A) = Some((a, a))
}

// added some definitions to make your question-code work
type Thing = String
type SomeInfo = String
type OtherInfo = String

object CoolStuff {
  def unapply(thing: Thing): Option[SomeInfo] = Some(thing.toLowerCase)
}
object NeatStuff {
  def unapply(thing: Thing): Option[OtherInfo] = Some(thing.toUpperCase)
}

def process(a: SomeInfo, b: OtherInfo) = s"[$a, $b]"

val res = "helloworld" match {
  case CoolStuff(someInfo) && NeatStuff(otherInfo) =>
     process(someInfo, otherInfo)
  case _ =>
}

println(res)
```

This prints

```
[helloworld, HELLOWORLD]
```

The idea is that identifiers (in particular, `&&` and `~` in cchantep's code) can be used as [infix operators in patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns). Therefore, the `match-case`

```
case CoolStuff(someInfo) && NeatStuff(otherInfo) =>
```

will be desugared into

```
case &&(CoolStuff(someInfo), NeatStuff(otherInfo)) =>
```

and then the `unapply` method method of `&&` will be invoked which simply duplicates its input.

In my code, the duplication is achieved by a straightforward `Some((a, a))`. In cchantep's code, it is done with fewer parentheses: `Some(t -> t)`. The arrow `->` comes from [ArrowAssoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html), which in turn is provided as an implicit conversion in `Predef`. This is just a quick way to create pairs, usually used in maps:

```
Map("hello" -> 42, "world" -> 58)
```

Another remark: notice that `&&` can be used multiple times:

```
case Foo(a) && Bar(b) && Baz(c) => ...
```

---

So... I don't know whether it's an answer or an extended comment to cchantep's answer, but maybe someone finds it useful.

Comment: I think that the following might be in some way misleading _The idea is that identifiers like && (or ~ in cchantep's code) can be used in infix notation_. Please see __Note__ in my answer. In particular, one can use not only `&&` or `~` but any other stable identifier like for example `object AndAlso` as long as it defines `unapply` method

Comment: @kasur Yeah, it's the same as with infix notation with types. For types, you can also write something like `Int Either String` instead of `Either[Int, String]`.

Comment: I was hoping you would probably want to edit your answer a little bit in regards to this particular phrase _"The idea is that identifiers like && (or ~ in cchantep's code) can be used in infix notation. Therefore"_. Cause in my opinion it sounds like you can only use some special identifiers only, like `&&`, `~`. But here there is nothing special about them.

Answer (score 2):

For those who might miss the details on how this magic actually works, just want to expand the answer by @cchantep anf @Andrey Tyukin (comment section does not allow me to do that).

Running *scalac* with *-Xprint:**parser*** option will give something along those lines (*scalac 2.11.12*)

```
def too(t: String) = t match {
    case $tilde(CoolStuff((a @ _)), NeatStuff((b @ _))) => $qmark$qmark$qmark
}
```

This basically shows you the initial steps compiler does while parsing source into AST.

**Important Note** here is that the rules why compiler makes this transformation are described in [Infix Operation Patterns](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns) and [Extractor Patterns](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#extractor-patterns). In particular, this allows you to use any object as long as it has `unapply` method, like for example `CoolStuff(a) AndAlso NeatStuff(b)`. In previous answers `&&` and `~` were picked up as also possible *but not the only available valid identifiers*.

If running *scalac* with option *-Xprint:**patmat*** which is a special phase for translating *pattern matching* one can see something similar to this

```
def too(t: String): Nothing = {
  case <synthetic> val x1: String = t;
  case9(){
    <synthetic> val o13: Option[(String, String)] = main.this.~.unapply[String](x1);
    if (o13.isEmpty.unary_!)
      {
        <synthetic> val p3: String = o13.get._1;
        <synthetic> val p4: String = o13.get._2;
        {
          <synthetic> val o12: Option[String] = main.this.CoolStuff.unapply(p3);
          if (o12.isEmpty.unary_!)
            {
              <synthetic> val o11: Option[String] = main.this.NeatStuff.unapply(p4);
              if (o11.isEmpty.unary_!)
                matchEnd8(scala.this.Predef.???)
```

Here `~.unapply` will be called on input parameter `t` which will produce Some((t,t)). The tuple values will be extracted into variables `p3` and `p4`. Then, `CoolStuff.unapply(p3)` will be called and if the result is not `None` `NeatStuff.unapply(p4)` will be called and also checked if it is not empty. If both are not empty then according to [Variable Patterns](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#variable-patterns) `a` and `b` will be bound to returned results inside corresponding `Some`.